# I'm having problems with object oriented programming

Tags: c++, oop, object-oriented-analysis

I'm having problem in my programming classes, basically we're learning about object oriented programming and I'm building a program, this is a part of the code:

```
float Pedido::calculaTotal() const {
    std::list<Produto*>::const_iterator it;
    float valorTotal;
    for (it = m_produtos.begin(); it != m_produtos.end(); ++it){
        int quantidade = it->getQtd();
        float valor = it->getValor();
        valorTotal += quantidade * valor;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
pedido.cpp: In member function ‘float Pedido::calculaTotal() const’:
pedido.cpp:20:30: error: request for member ‘getQtd’ in ‘* it.std::_List_const_iterator<Produto*>::operator->()’, which is of pointer type ‘Produto* const’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
         int quantidade = it->getQtd();
                              ^~~~~~

pedido.cpp:21:27: error: request for member ‘getValor’ in ‘* it.std::_List_const_iterator<Produto*>::operator->()’, which is of pointer type ‘Produto* const’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
         float valor = it->getValor();
```

Comment: Why are you using a list of pointers?  Pointers make programs more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is almost correct, you just need a couple of corrections.
You need to initialize total to zero and then return it in the end.

```
float Pedido::calculaTotal() const {
    std::list<Produto*>::const_iterator it;
    float valorTotal = 0;
    for (it = m_produtos.begin(); it != m_produtos.end(); ++it){
        Produto* p = *it;
        int quantidade = p->getQtd();
        float valor = p->getValor();
        valorTotal += quantidade * valor;
    }
  return valorTotal;
}
```

Also the iterator is a "pointer" itself so `*it` has the type of `Produto*` and to get the actual `Produto` object you need to dereference twice with either `(*it)->` or alternatively do what I did above, get the pointer with `Produto* p = *it;` then use the actual pointer with `p->`.

Alternatively you can also use ranges like this:

```
float Pedido::calculaTotal() const {
    float valorTotal = 0;
    for ( Produto* p : m_produtos ) {
        valorTotal += p->getQtd() * p->getValor();
    }
    return valorTotal;
}
```